# Take music files on memory card using phonegap for android music player

Tags: android, cordova, android-music-player

I am trying to create a music player using phonegap for android.How could I collect the mp3 files in my memory card to list in my player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html
using this api u can search the whole file hierchy, save paths of all mp3's which u find using regex and then display a list.
Also you can show it folder wise by also saving the folder info and other info.